# Swift - Have a "Loading" ViewController in between the NavBar and TabBar while TableView loads its contents

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a TabBarController as my rootViewController. The first tab is a tableView with a NavigationBar. While the tableView is performing its fetch request and loading its contents, I present a loading viewController with a loading indicator. The loadingVC doesn't cover the tabBar, which is great, but it does cover the NavBar, which I'd like to avoid. I'd essentially like the loadingVC to be placed in between the NavBar and the TabBar, so having its views frame be bound - its top to the bottom of the NavBar and its bottom to the top of the TabBar. I can't get this functionality to work and I thought I'd be able to find a solution in .modalPresentationStyle but the options there don't cover what I'm describing.

Scene Delegate Code:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    
    let rootVC = TBController()
    window?.rootViewController = rootVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

TabBarController:

```
class TBController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    
    // Article TVC
    let articleVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ArticlesTVC())

    let articleIcon = UITabBarItem(title: "News", image: UIImage(systemName: "newspaper"), tag: 0)
    articleVC.tabBarItem = articleIcon
    articleVC.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    articleVC.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    articleVC.navigationBar.barTintColor = .systemBackground
    articleVC.definesPresentationContext = true
    articleVC.view.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Loading VC:

```
class LoadingVC: UIViewController {

var loadingLabel: UILabel = {
    let loadingLabel = UILabel()
    loadingLabel.text = "Loading articles..."
    loadingLabel.textAlignment = .center
    loadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loadingLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .heavy)
    loadingLabel.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    return loadingLabel
}()

var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    
    indicator.style = .large
    indicator.color = .white
    indicator.startAnimating()

    indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    indicator.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    return indicator
}()

var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.clipsToBounds = true
    blurEffectView.alpha = 0.8
    
    blurEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blurEffectView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    return blurEffectView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    view.addSubview(loadingLabel)
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    
    view.addSubview(loadingActivityIndicator)
    loadingActivityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loadingActivityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(loadingLabel)
    loadingLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loadingLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    
    
}
}
```

TableView:

```
class ArticlesTVC: UITableViewController {

let loadingVC = LoadingVC()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    loadingVC.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    loadingVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(self.loadingVC, animated: true)
    }

    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better having it as a view above your tableView and assign true to its isHidden property when your content has loaded.  It’s a little messy in the storyboard, although there are ways around that, but in your case you are adding to your view controller’s view programmatically, anyway, so adding your code to a custom view instead and then adding that view over your table view should be no problem. You can then call the custom view’s methods as you please.

Comment: I like that idea but I can't get it to work. I've moved the LoadingVC code into a LoadingView UIView instead. I've created a global loadingView variable in ArticlesTVC and tried adding loadingView as a subview of tableView or navigationController.view in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but it won't show. Any ideas?

Comment: You could add it as a subview of the ArticlesTVC’s view.  You might have to assign it the right z value (how far forward it is in the screen). Have you tried adding it as a subview of ArticlesTVC’s view?

Comment: Also, I would avoid a needless global and just make your view a property of the ArticlesTVC, and just assign to it’s isHidden property true or false.  Sorry I’m not more useful but I’m used to working with storyboards.

Comment: I tried adding it as a subview of ArticlesTVC and then assigning it a z value but it still won't show for some reason. Tried it with navController.view and tableView as well but no luck. Appreciate the ideas though!

Comment: Did you make sure the tableView had a lesser z-value?

Comment: Yes I just tried again and set the loadingView's z position to 1 and the tableViews to 0 and still no luck